# linguistic term for those not immediatly present

Tags: present

Is there a term (or terms) in linguistics for speaking about those not immediately present? Something like Mental Time Travel (Chronesthesia).

In other words people can speak of those not here right now, but animals cannot communicate in that way.

What is the term for that ability? I thought I read about it somewhere but cannot remember it.

Answer (score 4):

It is usually known as [displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(linguistics)).